# How to select a column from a named range

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges

I have a named range, let it be `MyRange` it is defined as `'MySheet'!J5:L68`
Is there any way to calculate a `SUM` in the second column of a Range?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible. just use `INDEX`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(MyRange,,2))
```